client connecting to server works with python, but not with kotlin ktor
I am connecting to a web server that returns binary data to me. Using the below python code, I am able to output the results:
from struct import unpack_from
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  
PORT = 12345  

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    while True:
        data = s.recv(7000)
        print(f"type: {type(data)}, size: {len(data)}, data: {data[0:10]}")


output result >>> type: <class 'bytes'>, size: 6985, data: b'\x00\x00\x1bE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00'

However, when I try to do the same with ktor using their example with the below code:
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.websocket.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*


fun main() {
    val client = HttpClient {
        install(WebSockets)
    }
    runBlocking {
        client.webSocket(method = HttpMethod.Get, host = "127.0.0.1", port = 12345) {
            while(true) {
                val othersMessage = incoming.receive() as? Frame.Binary ?: continue
                println(othersMessage.readBytes())
            }
        }
    }
    client.close()
    println("Connection closed. Goodbye!")
}

I get hit with an Exception: Unsupported byte code, first byte is 0x92.
Not sure what is going wrong or how I can debug this. Any ideas please?

The Python code uses a "bare bones" TCP socket while the Kotlin code uses a websocket. A websocket works with a specific protocol to transmit frames (binary or string messages of a defined length) instead of the byte stream of the TCP socket.

You can find information about how to work with the TCP/IP sockets using Ktor in the documentation (https://ktor.io/docs/server-sockets.html#client).

Michael, Aleksei, thank u both. it didn't occur to me about it. Let me check it out!

Like what Michael and Aleksei mentioned in the comments, I was using the wrong protocol when calling from TCP socket.
the link shared by Aleksei here is the correct way to connect to tcp sockets in ktor.
